# How to get formatted facts from Ansible module vmware_vm_facts?

Tags: ansible

I tried to get virtual machines facts from ESXi with Ansible. 
My playbook here:

```
- name: VM
  local_action:
    module: vmware_vm_facts
    hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
    username: root.
    password: '{{ esxi_root_passw }}'
    validate_certs: no
  register: instance_vm_facts

- debug: var=instance_vm_facts
```

And i got some results:

`ok: [localhost -> localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "hostname": "192.168.210.63",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "username": "root",
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "virtual_machines": {
        "vmware-test-1": {
            "guest_fullname": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)",
            "ip_address": "192.168.108.91",
            "power_state": "poweredOn"
        },
        "vmware-test-2”: {
            "guest_fullname": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)",
            "ip_address": "192.168.109.24",
            "power_state": "poweredOn"
        }
    }
}`

But i understand how to filter only name and ip_address?
I tried  with_item and with_dict but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate on virtual machines, you have to use `instance_vm_facts.virtual_machines`.
As it's not a list, you have to use `with_dict` and then access name with `item.key` and IP with `item.value.ip_address`, or power state with `item.value.power_state`, ...

```
- debug:
    msg: "IP of {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.ip_address }}"
  with_dict: "{{ instance_vm_facts.virtual_machines }}"
```